# What is the easiest way to maintain a list of key-value pairs sorted by value?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

Each key is unique in the list. When a new key-value pair arrives, the pair is inserted into the list in the ascending order of value (if key already exists then updates the value).

Please avoid sorting the list for every insertion.

Comment: sounds like homework - if it is tag it?

Comment: Try using a linked list pattern.  Run through the list checking your comparison/sort as keys.  If you find a matching key, replace the value.  Otherwise keep searching until you find a key that sorts "higher" than the one you're inserting; once you find it insert before that item.  If you hit the end of the list, insert it at the end.  EDIT: could also wrap an underlying `List<T>` object with its insert methods; it'd have to rebuild/reorgnize an underlying array, but it's alright. Since you haven't specified performance requirements, not sure what you need to use.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair  My first thought is almost the same as yours, just wonders if any cleaner way out there to do it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest SortedDictionary or SortedList

As per MSDN :

> SortedList uses less memory than SortedDictionary.
>
> SortedDictionary has faster insertion and removal
>   operations for unsorted data: O(log n) as opposed to O(n) for
>   SortedList.

Update : After comments

You will have to order the value by yourself for e.g using a dictioanry

```
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>{ {1, "Z"}, {2, "A"}};
    IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> orderedEnumerable = dictionary.OrderBy(d => d.Value);
```

Comment: Both collections sort by key, not by value.

Comment: as dtb indicates, both sorts by key not value

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to get a built in component with this behaviour, it's too non-standard. I'd be looking at why and when I needed these competing behaviours. Effectively you are looking at an alternate key. Short of just writing some for of linked list, off the top of my head, I'd look at SortedList for the by value part of it, and a Dictionary for key.
e.g.

a Dictionary of CustomerID and SortKey and a SortedList of SortKey and value.

I'd try and avoid it if I could on the baiss that maintaining both would cost more than simply returning a list of values in the required order on those occasions when you needed it.

Answer (score 0):

If sorting the items for every enumeration is acceptable, you can use a [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) and order the key-value pairs by value when you enumerate it:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<MyKey, MyValue>();

// insertion (updates value when key already exists)
dict[key] = value;

// enumeration (ordered by value)
foreach (var keyValuePair in dict.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write an ad-hoc class like the following (not completely tested):

```
public class DictionarySortedByValue<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    class ValueWrapper : IComparable, IComparable<ValueWrapper>
    {
        public TKey Key { get; private set; }
        public TValue Value { get; private set; }

        public ValueWrapper(TKey k, TValue v)
        {
            this.Key = k;
            this.Value = v;
        }
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (!(obj is ValueWrapper))
                throw new ArgumentException("obj is not a ValueWrapper type object");
            return this.CompareTo(obj as ValueWrapper);
        }
        public int CompareTo(ValueWrapper other)
        {
            int c = Comparer<TValue>.Default.Compare(this.Value, other.Value);
            if (c == 0)
                c = Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(this.Key, other.Key);
            return c;
        }
    }

    private SortedSet<ValueWrapper> orderedElements;
    private SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> innerDict;

    public DictionarySortedByValue()
    {
        this.orderedElements = new SortedSet<ValueWrapper>();
        this.innerDict = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        var wrap = new ValueWrapper(key, value);
        this.innerDict.Add(key, value);
        this.orderedElements.Add(wrap);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return this.innerDict.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get { return this.innerDict.Keys; }
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        TValue val;
        if (this.TryGetValue(key, out val))
        {
            var wrap = new ValueWrapper(key, val);
            this.orderedElements.Remove(wrap);
            this.innerDict.Remove(key);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        return this.innerDict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get { return this.innerDict.Values; }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.innerDict[key];
        }
        set
        {
            bool removed = this.Remove(key);
            this.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        this.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.innerDict.Clear();
        this.orderedElements.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        var wrap = new ValueWrapper(item.Key,item.Value);
        return this.orderedElements.Contains(wrap);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        this.innerDict.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.innerDict.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        if (this.Contains(item))
            return this.Remove(item.Key);
        return false;
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var el in this.orderedElements)
            yield return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(el.Key, el.Value);
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

**Notes :**

- it requires that also the `TKey` type implements IComparable.
- the posted code uses only the default Comparer for TKey, and TValue, but
  you could pass a custom one through another constructor.